# jquery changed class does not react

Tags: jquery

When I click the word Hello that has the class oldClass, the jquery changes the class to the class newClass, which colours the word Hello blue. This means the class was changed. Why does jquery not respond to clicking the class newClass?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".oldClass").click(function(){
            $(".oldClass").attr("class","newClass");
        });
        $(".newClass").click(function(){
            $(".newClass").attr("class","oldClass");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .oldClass {color:red;}
    .newClass {color:blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="oldClass">Hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9e06kmo/)

Comment: FYI: jQuery implements addClass and removeClass functions https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 4):

Delegate you click events

```
 $('body').on('click','.oldClass',function(){
    $(".oldClass").attr("class","newClass");
 });
 $('body').on('click','.newClass',function(){
    $(".newClass").attr("class","oldClass");
 });
```

Better to use toggleClass

```
$('body').on('click','.oldClass,.newClass',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('newClass oldClass');
     });
```

Comment: We meet again!  ;) I will try that, and I will follow Chakri's advice with toggleClass.

Comment: Madalin Ivascu, I don't really see how to fit that into what I am trying to do. The example above is a simple example. What I am trying to do is append new rows with 4 fields (first name, last name, user, pass) and a "X" (cross) .png. When the "X" is clicked the row is deleted. This works fine but not with newly created appended rows. The rows are assigned an ID when created, but clicking the "X" .png does not trigger in jQuery. Can you please copy my code above, edit it and paste it again?

Comment: @Kobbe select the row closest to the button using closest, for example `$('img.delete').closest('.row').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Better use 
         toggleClass('oldClass newClass');

Answer (score 0):

Because newClass in not present at the time of event binding.
You need to attach event whenever class is changed
Use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    function bindOldClassClick(){
     $(".oldClass").click(function(){
            $(".oldClass").attr("class","newClass");
            bindNewClassClick();
     });
    }
    function bindNewClassClick(){
        $(".newClass").click(function(){
           $(".newClass").attr("class","oldClass");
           bindOldClassClick();
      });
    }
    bindOldClassClick();
});
```

check this on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9w0z95ru/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. hope this will help to you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style>
p{
 cursor:pointer;
}

.newClass{
 color: red;
 
}

.oldClass{
 color: black;
 
}
</style>

<body>
 
<p class="oldClass">This is my paragraph - use me</p>




</body>

<script type="text/javascript">


// CHECK WHICH THE CLASS NAME AND CHANGE
$("p").click(function(){
 var theClassname = $(this).attr('class');

 if(theClassname == "oldClass")
 {
  $(this).attr('class','newClass');
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).attr('class','oldClass');
 }

}); 




</script>
</html>
```